# Backbone model events/triggers not firing

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-events

Having seen it in a couple of tutorials, I'm trying to execute the following line of code in my view

```
@model.on('change', @render, this)
```

Unfortunately the change event is not firing and therefore my view is not re-rendering.

I've tried binding to different events and creating a couple of custom events using the trigger function but nothing seems to be firing at all on the model. Furthermore, there are no errors coming from the console. The change event is working fine on a different collection. I'm using Zepto 1.0, Backbone.js 0.9.2 and Underscore.js 1.3.1

EDIT: I'm trying to execute the following from the Router

```
  place: (id) ->
    @model = new GM.Models.Place({id: "#{id}"})
    @model.fetch
    view = new GM.Views.Place(model: @model)
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)
```

And my model is set up like this:

```
class GM.Models.Place extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: '/mobile/place'
```

I am wondering if anyone has experienced similar problems before and has a quick fix.
If not and you need more of the code to find an explanation please let me know...

Comment: What is executing that you are expecting would fire a change event?

Comment: I'm expecting that fetching a specific model should fire a change event, as per the code added above. Any thoughts?

Comment: Calling `.fetch()` does.  Try it, as explained in @mu's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually calling the `@model.fetch` method anywhere. This:

```
@model.fetch
```

is not a method call, you need to add parentheses or arguments if you want to call the method:

```
@model.fetch()
# or
@model.fetch success: -> ...
# etc.
```

Otherwise you're just producing `this.model.fetch;` in the JavaScript and that doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe this - rookie mistake, still getting used to Coffeescript...!

Comment: @socratic_singh: A lot of people (including me) always include the parentheses just to avoid having to worry about when you need them and when you don't.

Comment: Will definitely be doing that from hereonin. Thanks again

Comment: @socratic_singh: They can also help with grouping [multi-line function calls](http://coffeescript.org/#try:some_function(%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20'a'%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20'b'%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20blahblah()%3B%0A)%0Asomething_else('pancakes')) to make the structure easier to see; I find the indentation-based structure difficult to grok at a glance when things get nested (especially with the 2 character indent that many people insist on using).